# How can i create a jar of a java project which contains src/main/java and src/test/java with dependencies using maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

**How can i create a jar of a java project which contains src/main/java and src/test/java with dependencies using maven.**

**Note:test cases should not be run at the time of jar creation.**

i have used this **mvn clean compile assembly:single to generate jar** that generates jar contains only **src/main/java** and **dependencies** but **not src/test/java.**

can any one please tell me how can i resolve this problem.Is the problem due pom file.What should i mension in pom to get.

**my project structure looks like this:**

[image]
thank you

Comment: This is the way Maven works. Why should test classes be delivered in the JAR file?

Comment: i need to run selenium testcases on different machines by copying this jar

Comment: Did you ever look into the [documentation of the Maven JAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/)? There you will find your answer. In fact, you should better read more documentation prior to asking questions.

Comment: yes.when i add maven goal as jar:test-jar then run it will not generating test classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use..

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

I think you don't have dependency package plugin. Add this in your pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: thank you .but this command does not include maven dependency jars

Comment: thank you.it creates me 3 jars.can't we make a single jar or main and dependencies one jar and test cases other jar

Answer (score -1):

Why dont youput your program into eclipse then

```
File->Export->Java->Runnable JAR file-> Save Location-> finish
```

your jar file will be in the save location.

Comment: i know this but i want to automate this process with out manual export